# What is the question mark for in a Typescript parameter name

Tags: typescript

```
export class Thread {
  id: string;
  lastMessage: Message;
  name: string;
  avatarSrc: string;

  constructor(id?: string,
              name?: string,
              avatarSrc?: string) {
    this.id = id || uuid();
    this.name = name;
    this.avatarSrc = avatarSrc;
  }
}
```

In `id?` what's the `?` for?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

It is to mark the parameter as **optional**.

- TypeScript handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters
- TypeScript Deep Dive https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/functions#optional-parameters

Comment: I have seen $ symbol at the end of variable names. What does that mean?

Comment: It is not related to TypeScript. I have seen such syntax in RxJs projects. From the doc: it is a "common RxJS convention to identify variables that reference a stream." https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/docs/basics/Epics.md#a-basic-example

Comment: @SunilGarg $ postfix is usually a naming convention to mean the variable is an observable.

Comment: What if the question mark is used in class properties? the links didn't resolve this.

Comment: It's worth adding that if you have a parameter `foo?: string`, then inside the function, the type of `foo` becomes `string | undefined`. Note that declaring `foo?: string` is nonetheless different from `foo: string | undefined`, because with `string | undefined`, callers are forced to explicitly pass `undefined`.

Comment: @NeoZoom.lua For class properties, the behavior is analogous to function parameters – declaring `foo?: string;` means that `"foo"` is optional, and the type of `instance.foo` becomes `string | undefined`.

Comment: @JoLiss Thank you. This is pure fortune that I finally got an answer and your comment is read because I've been re-learning frontend recently. Do you have a link to the information source btw? I'm not doubting it, but I'm a big fan of making notes.

Answer (score 67):

#### `parameter?: type` is a shorthand for `parameter: type | undefined`

**So what is the difference?** Question mark means "optional".
More precisely `parameter?: type` is equal to `parameter: type | undefined = undefined`

Comment: Not exactly. Question mark means "optional". So it's a shorthand for "parameter: type | undefined = undefined"..

Comment: Actually, it does not default to `undefined`, but rather to nonexistence. 

Masih's answer is correct:
`parameter?: type` is a shorthand for `parameter: type | undefined`

Note how differently `= undefined` behaves in [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/FAYwNghgzlAEUAsD2AnALgiA7AJgcQFcBPWAb2AEgsIBbAUwC540UBLLAc1gF5YByAGIo6OPpUSoM2HAH4mUFuw4BucYs4B5FAFVcdAGbsR89VwA+sAnsNYRqijgMQCYNABUkuxzePM2nWAsrbyMcHktrUNUAX2BgMDo0WH1hRzYQAGtw2wB3eGR0TFxCIgAKAEpVUCQsKCQEgDowJA5SlJE6dIzy4CA).

Comment: @lodewykk It's not exactly a shorthand, either. `param?: type` declares the parameter as optional, `param: type | undefined` doesn't. Example: `const foo: { a?: string } = {}` works but `const foo: { a: string | undefined } = {}` fails. Meanwhile, in function declarations @mcoolive is right and `arg?: type` is equivalent to `arg: type | undefined = undefined`, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name/63338805#63338805

Comment: This is answer is not correct. The `?` designator (not sure what it technically is classified as) is not shorthand for `type | undefined`. It's true that optional parameters will have a value of `undefined` at run time if they are not specified but as @balu pointed out `type | undefined` requires you to actually specify a value of that type or `undefined` or you'll get a compiler error. The optional `?` thingy does not require you to specify a value.

Answer (score 47):

This is to make the **variable of Optional type.** Otherwise declared variables shows "**undefined**" if this variable is not used.

```
export interface ISearchResult {  
  title: string;  
  listTitle:string;
  entityName?: string,
  lookupName?:string,
  lookupId?:string  
}
```

Comment: I do not agree that it indicates a "nullable" type. It indicates optional, not nullable. It is still valid, for instance, for `title` in the example above to have a value of `null` but it would be invalid for a class that claims to implement `ISearchResult` to be missing an `entityName` property at compile time.

Comment: I think the correct name is "optional parameter". Nullable type would be `string?`. To have an optional nullable, you'd do `name?: string?`.

Comment: @DvG Would you mind to improve your answer considering the comments by Josh Gallagher and user276648?

Comment: @user1460043.. I have updated my answer. Thanks for notifying me

Comment: I assume the phrasing "optional type" originates from languages like c++, scala, or python. Where you have a generic Optional<T> type. Actually, it would make more sense to put the `?` after the type specification instead of after the variable name. If you don't pass anything to `lookupId`, then it will not have type `string`.

Answer (score 10):

The `?` in the parameters is to denote an **optional parameter**. The Typescript compiler does not require this parameter to be filled in. See the code example below for more details:

```
// baz: number | undefined means: the second argument baz can be a number or undefined

// = undefined, is default parameter syntax, 
// if the parameter is not filled in it will default to undefined

// Although default JS behaviour is to set every non filled in argument to undefined 
// we need this default argument so that the typescript compiler
// doesn't require the second argument to be filled in
function fn1 (bar: string, baz: number | undefined = undefined) {
    // do stuff
}

// All the above code can be simplified using the ? operator after the parameter
// In other words fn1 and fn2 are equivalent in behaviour
function fn2 (bar: string, baz?: number) {
    // do stuff
}



fn2('foo', 3); // works
fn2('foo'); // works

fn2();
// Compile time error: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0
// An argument for 'bar' was not provided.


fn1('foo', 3); // works
fn1('foo'); // works

fn1();
// Compile time error: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0
// An argument for 'bar' was not provided.
```

Answer (score 2):

As of TypeScript 4.7, this is how the compiler would treat these scenarios:

```
interface OptTest {
  test: string
  test2: string
  test3?: string
  test4?: string | null
  test5: string | null
  test6: null
}

const testVar: OptTest = {} 
// Type '{}' is missing the following 
// properties from type 'OptTest': test, test2, test5, test6
```