# Transforming pipes in angular 2 with typescript

Tags: typescript

Can you please explain to me what **`args?`** means in the following code sample:

`transform(value: any, args?: any): any {...`

I'm new to programming and asking for help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the question mark for in a Typescript parameter name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example `transform(value: any, args?: any)`, `value` is the value from the interpolated variable, ie `{{myVar}}`, and args are any additional pipe arguments passed in.  For example:

```
{{ myVar| myPipe: arg1}}
```

This uses the pipe `myPipe` and passes in an argument named `arg1` that would map to `args?` in the `transform` method.