# What type of syntax is this and what does it mean? 'variable?: value'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

here's some examples of code that uses the `?` symbol

```
export type Props = {
  /**
   * The CSS class name of the scroll button elements.
   */
  buttonClassName?: string,
}
```

`tabs: ?HTMLElement = undefined;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name

Comment: @epascarello thanks, but this is in a .js file. That's where my confusion lies.

Comment: `->` https://flow.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be something used by [flow](https://flow.org): It means that `tabs` and `buttonClassName` are optional (i.e. `undefined` is allowed). See the [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#optional-parameters-a-classtoc-idtoc-optional-parameters-hreftoc-optional-parametersa) for more details. They also have an [example](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/) of it being used with React.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured this out. It is indeed flow (// @flow was at the top of the .js file I'm looking at)

Answer (score 1):

This is used in type casting for javascript / react components using Flow.

Lets get to your example

```
export type Props = {
  buttonClassName?: string,
}
```

These props are exported (mostly for button class). It means that for some button component a prop of buttonClassName is an optional parameter (due to the ?) and its data type is a string. If there was no ?. A warning would be thrown in the dev environment.

Another Example how this is used

```
type ButtonProps = {
  label: string,
  onClick: Function,
  styleClass?: {[key: string]: string}
};

class ButtonComponent extends Component<ButtonProps> {
... other code

}
```

Now if you were to use `<ButtonComponent />` in your code you would have to do

```
<ButtonComponent 
  label="Confirm"
  onClick={someClickHandlerFunction}
  styleClass={a style object}
/>
```

Now notice the styleClass in the props. The syntax means that it will be an object and the question mark means its optional. This way while you're developing a lot of errors that can arise due to undefined objects etc can be avoided.

```
<ButtonComponent 
  label="Confirm"
  styleClass={a style object}
/>
```

This would throw a warning, as a onClick prop hasnt been passed. This way you can eliminate a lot of possible bugs.

I recommend using the Atom Plugin for Flow which lints your code as you develop.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely be adding that plugin