# Does property? mean that the property can be null or undefined on class instances?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For this typescript interface:

```
    export interface Person {
    phone?: number;
    name?: string;
}
```

Does this mean that the name property on class instances of the interface can be null or undefined?

For example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name) asks a similar question which indicates that it makes the parameter optional.  But what does optional mean in the context of an interface?  For example suppose I have a class that implements the interface:

```
class Customer implements Person {
}
```

Did I now implement Person correctly because all the properties on the `Person` interface are optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the name property on class instances of the interface can be null or undefined?

Yes, it means exactly that.

> But what does optional mean in the context of an interface?

It means that you can implement the Interface without setting all the properties.

Here's an example.

```
interface Person{
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}

var b: Person = { name: 'Bob' }; // OK
var c: Person = { name: 'Bob', age: undefined }; // OK
var d: Person = { name: null, age: 'bob' }; // Not OK, age must be a number
```

OR

```
class SomePerson implements Person{
    public name = 'Bob';
}
```

OR

```
class SomeOtherPerson implements Person{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) is the documentation you're looking for.

> The advantage of optional properties is that you can describe these possibly available properties while still also preventing use of properties that are not part of the interface.

And yes, you proprerly implemented `Person` with your `Customer` class.