# Optional parameters on TypeScript interfaces

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name), the `?` operator can be used to mark a function parameter as optional.  What does the `?` operator mean on interface parameters?  For example, if we have this TypeScript interface:

```
export interface Person {
    phone?: number;
    name?: string;
}
```

And a class that implements the interface:

```
class Customer implements Person {
}
```

Did `Customer` now implement Person correctly because all the properties on the `Person` interface are optional?

Comment: Whether a class implements an interface correctly can be trivially answered by running the Typescript compiler.

Comment: a hint on interfaces in TS. this also implements the interface correctly: `let somebody:Person = {};` you don't need to explicitely `implements Person` on a class

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The short answer is yes. `Customer` correctly implements `Person` since all fields of the interface are optional. Any object will correctly implement the interface.

The usefulness of this interface is:

- On the implementer site, if any optional field is declared, the type must correspond (so `phone` has to be defined as `number`)
- On the receiving side (for example, as a function parameter), you can only access fields that are potentially part of `Person` (you should check if they are `undefined`), but the function, for example, guarantees it will not access any other fields of a `Person` parameter.

Comment: Whether it compiles or not, isn't this violating the I in SOLID? Interface segregation? Does it make sense when I tell you I have a device (a class) and a remote control (interface) but half of the buttons don't do anything for this device? Isn't the remote control made too generic then?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk it's up to you how you define the interface. The remote may have any number of functionalities, it just happens you got one with no functionality, but that is clearly stated in the interface contract as a possibility (since all members are optional) and is up to the user of the interface to check what he got

Comment: Haha. you all said it perfectly:)