# What does ? mean in Angular function arguments?

Tags: angular, typescript

While going through an Angular 4 tutorial I found a new way of getting/setting parameter in function.

```
onValueChange(data?: any)
```

What does the `?` do?

Comment: It means it is optional to send parameter to this function. it won't throw error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the question mark for in a Typescript parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` sign denotes `optional`. Meaning that if you don't pass the value to function, it won't throw an `error`.

> **For example:**

This is your function

```
onValueChange(data?: any) {
  console.log(data);
}
onValueChange('somedata'); // will print 'somedata' in the console
onValueChange(); // will print undefined but it won't throw an error
```

**Summary:** You can call this function without passing the value as it is optional.

Answer (score 1):

It is an optional parameter.we can pass this parameter or if we don't pass this parameter then it will not give error.We can call function like this:

```
onValueChange('somedata');
onValueChange();
```

Answer (score 1):

It defines **optional**. Once you define a `fucntion/method` like that. You can either pass a **value** Or **Not**.

`onValueChange(data?: any) {}` can be used as like `onValueChange() {}` too. when you have function definition defined like this `onValueChange(data?: any) {}`.

Similarly when you can create models In the same manner you can use it too.

**For example :**

```
 export class YOURCLASS{
        ids?: number[];
        name :string
   }
```

In this case too you can either have ids array or not but definietly have to have name parameter instead.

Comment: No problem happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, every parameter is optional, and users may leave them off as they see fit. When they do, their value is undefined. We can get this functionality in TypeScript by adding a ? to the end of parameters we want to be optional.

So in here, it says you can either pass some values on bound value change event for you van just call the function on event occurrence.