# What is the dash-question mark syntax in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, syntax, option-type

I **don't** mean the [question mark syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37632760/500207), rather, I'm asking about `-?` in, for example:

```
type Required<T> =
  T extends object
    ? { [P in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[P]>; } // <---------- "-?" here
    : T;
```

via [this 2018 GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15012#issuecomment-365453623). I cannot find this syntax in the TypeScript handbook's chapters on [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) nor [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

`-?` as above still compiles in TypeScript 3.8, and appears to be the *opposite* of `?`, i.e., making the key required? Is it equivalent to [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt)? If not, what is this syntax called and where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are basically right: it removes the optional property modifier `?` from a [mapped type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  It was introduced in TypeScript 2.8 as part of [improvements to control over mapped type modifiers (see this link for the docs you want)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers).  It's not *identical* to the [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt) utility type, but `Required` is [implemented with it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#example-6) (see [library definition here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1445-L1450)) and could not exist without it.

It's a sad fact that TypeScript documentation is kind of spread out between the handbook, release notes, FAQ, outdated spec, and GitHub issues, without a clear canonical place to look for any particular thing.  The language has been evolving more quickly than the documentation can keep up.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!