# Understanding a function definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

What does ? and | mean in a functions definision such as this one?

```
export function readFileSync(path: PathLike | number, options: { encoding: BufferEncoding; flag?: string; } | BufferEncoding): string;
```

Thank you,

Comment: It is a union operator, tells `PathLike | number` it can be type of PathLike OR number.

Comment: See also [What is the question mark for in a Typescript parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37632760/215552)

Comment: The term "join" is not used; it is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

Comment: Oh yes, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` denotes an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties).

> Not all properties of an interface may be required. Some exist under certain conditions or may not be there at all. These optional properties are popular when creating patterns like “option bags” where you pass an object to a function that only has a couple of properties filled in.

The `|` is the [union type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types). It is sort of like an "or" operator, denoting that the type has multiple options that will satisfy it.