# Why does TypeScript `never` type require question mark ? for conditional objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

This code works fine to conditionally require the `isDirty` field to be part of a lecture object:

- If `id` is of type `string`, I must add an `isDirty` field:
- If `id` is of type `number`, I cannot add an `isDirty` field to the object.

```
type LectureT = LectureIdT & {
  title: string;
};

/**
 * Lecture must have an `isDirty` field if `id` is of type string, but should have no `isDirty` field if `id` if of type number.
 */
type LectureIdT =
  | { id: string; isDirty: boolean }
  | { id: number; isDirty?: never };
  

const lectureMockWithNumberId: LectureT = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Lecture 1',
  // isDirty: false, // Uncomment to see error
};

const lectureMockWithStringId: LectureT = {
  id: "1",
  title: 'Lecture 2',
  isDirty: false,
};
```

This code can be played around with in this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhDGwCuAnCAVKBeWDloEkATTAMigG8AoKKYAS2ABsIAuKAZ2BXoDsBzANxUAvsKoB6AFRSaU3IlTR4AQ15QA9ryYgoACxUA3aPQ4AReilBQAZvQhMiUejedPTm16EhReSALYARhAoAHRyElTe0HCKhCTYNFAAPpRu7Fw8AoLO5pag7IEaGixqUCJJqRTpvgHBKDmmFlYgAPzsvBDGKOXCtFRU8FpcUCxxEACyGvAA1gDqjHoAcnUhxOyx+BjYlEn0ROwAjAA0SQzMbFAA5JtKUIdXp7QSErnNBbYqTBwQx1AvUAAqrwhv5-BBeMA6BpOBBoCEUBoUKJxENeCMxlsprMFsA9ABlbh8fjrBRbTA4ai0fbsABEh1pTzojBY7BueDuACZHns8i12DYvj9TmIqEA).

**Question**: Why do I need the question mark in `isDirty?: never`?

---

**My investigations of the matter**:

When I remove the question mark from `isDirty?: never` to get `isDirty: never` it doesn't work anymore:

```
type LectureIdT =
  | { id: string; isDirty: boolean }
  | { id: number; isDirty: never };
```

`lectureMockWithNumberId` suddenly has a TypeScript error:

```
Type '{ id: number; title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'LectureT'.
  Type '{ id: number; title: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; isDirty: never; } & { title: string; }'.
    Property 'isDirty' is missing in type '{ id: number; title: string; }' but required in type '{ id: number; isDirty: never; }'.
```

We see in the last sentence that it says that `isDirty` is required. But this does not seem right to me! Its type is `never` -> So it should **never** be required, shouldn't it?

Why do I have to add a question mark to make it work. That seems unlogical.

In an attempt to make sense of it I changed it to `isDirty: never | undefined`:

```
type LectureIdT =
  | { id: string; isDirty: boolean }
  | { id: number; isDirty: never | undefined };
```

But to my surprise the error remains! Doesn't the `?` in e.g. `a?: string` equal `a: string | undefined`?

I don't understand...

1. ...why the question mark `?` is necessary here in the first place and `isDirty: never;` is basically impossible.
2. ...why `?` behaves differently when it's used together with `never`?

Comment: "*Doesn't the ? in e.g. a?: string equal a: string | undefined?*" not exactly. It means that the property `a` might not exist. `{ b: "world" }` is a valid object with an optional `a` property. It just doesn't have it.

Comment: do you really need the definition for `isDirty?: never`? What happens when you remove the property?

Comment: @Sysix Yes, I do. If I remove `isDirty?: never;` and uncomment the line `// isDirty: false, // Uncomment to see error` you will see that now TypeScript doesn't complain although a lecture with an `id` of type `number` does have a `isDirty` field which I am preventing with the `never`. You can try it in the TS Playground I linked above.
Actually I am also asking myself why TypeScript is not complaining here... A bug in TypeScript?

Comment: @Andru No, it's not a bug. TypeScript allows any object that conforms to the interface, it only needs to have the required properties but is allowed to have any others.

Comment: @Bergi that's not right. [This TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhDGwCuAnCAVKBeKBvAUFFMAJbAA2EAXFAM7AokB2A5gNz4C+H+8A9k3pRKiVBACyfeAGsA6mQAWAOSQBbAEYQUASQAmNOKLSYcBIiX1QAjABpCxMpRoByQ8jTXnd7viA) refutes it. If I e.g. add `[key: string]: any;` to my object type I then can add any other properties in addition to the required properties.

Comment: [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are the exception, not the rule; they only happen when directly giving a type to an object literal.  So while `const bar: {a: number} = {a: 0, b: 1};` will give a warning,  `const foo = {a: 0, b: 1}; const bar: {a: number} = foo;` will compile without error.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, thanks for clarifying. This seems to be confused often. The comment in this reply elaborates on it. I.e. `a?: string` is equal to `a: string | undefined = undefined` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60038363/3210677

Comment: @Andru no, not equivalent [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoKUCGB+AXFAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcaUARnoaZTQL5QqiRQCaCyHdBkbFyFKAB8oAVzIATCADNyEOQBpaDAqMopWKFAGMA9mUJRFx4-ySY8AIgAWEADYvj9tfQcB3Y0Rc5eyhWGhMzYHoMIhtvKHs-AKCQmiNTcwAPAEY8OERLYzD0yJAc3n4C1PDMgCZc-jpoooioEDryxEaiKiA)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me take these questions one by one:

> We see in the last sentence that it says that `isDirty` is required. But this does not seem right to me! Its type is `never` -> So it should never be required, shouldn't it?

There is nothing unique about the `never` type in terms of how it interacts with optional object properties. You can think of `never` as the same as any other type (`string`, `number,` etc.). The difference is that unlike these other types, there are no values that are assignable to `never`. You might say that a variable of type `never` can "never" be assigned a valid value.

> But to my surprise the error remains! Doesn't the `?` in e.g. `a?: string` equal `a: string | undefined`?

No. Consider the difference between the two objects: `{}` and `{a: undefined}`. In one case the key is missing, completely. In the other it exists and has the value `undefined`. The former object is assignable to `{a?: string}` but not to `{a: string | undefined}`.

This leads to:

> why the question mark `?` is necessary here in the first place and `isDirty: never;` is basically impossible.

Like in the above example, if you do not include the `?` on the key name, then the key is *required* in the type. The key simply *has* to be present. But the type of that key's value is `never`. Because of that, there are no valid values you could assign to that key.

So in short, it is indeed impossible without a question mark, as it is a contradiction of requirements: that key must exist, but no value is valid for it.

Finally:

> why `?` behaves differently when it's used together with `never`.

This is merely a consequence of the usual properties of `never` combined with the usual behavior of `?`. There is nothing special about the interaction of these two particular features.

Using the example of `{isDirty?: never}`, this means that one of the following must be true:

- The object does *not* include the `isDirty` key.
- The object does include the `isDirty` key and it has a value of type `never`.

Since the second of those two cases is impossible (by the above arguments), that leaves only the first case: an object matching this type must not contain the `isDirty` key.

Comment: For reference: [microsoft/TypeScript#43954](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43954) seems to be a canonical answer to this question

Answer (score -1):

`never` is also known as an empty type - there's no value that exists in a set of `never` type. No value can be assigned to a variable of type `never`. Even when you write `function f(): never` - the function's return type is not `never` - it's just to specify, that the function `never` returns (exception is thrown or stuck in an infinite loop).

Apart from 'function doesn't return' I don't know any other use case for `never`.

Comment: As you see in my question I am using `never` in a different use case to the one you're mentioning which has nothing to do with this question.