# Typescript interface is reading optional string a string, instead of string | undefined

Tags: typescript

I have a class called `FilterType` , and an interface extending it. For some reason the interface is not getting the field types defined correctly.

```js
export class FilterType {
  operator: string;
  property?: string;
  value?: string;
  filters: Array<FilterType>
}

export interface IGenericFilter extends Omit<FilterType, "filters"> {
  filters?: IGenericFilter
}
```

When using IGenericFilter, typescript is evaluating `value` field as `string` instead of `string | undefined`. Why is this happening ? Shouldn't it be inferred as `string | undefined` since the class definition is `value ?: string`

```js
myFilter : IGenericFilter = {...}

const {value: myValue} = myFilter
// myValue is read as string, and not `string | undefined`
```

Typescript Version: 4.3.5

tsconfig :

```json
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2018",
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DECWSbBQAqAnmMHAN4BQccE5UKM0AXHGjFDgHYDmAblpwwUBoRgkA-O07d+QugDcUSAK7AZHLr0HCAZngJQ07AIJQmJADy58hUuQB81AL7VqoSLDi9j+lAQKAEkAcWAeQhwEO2M4UAIeABNMAHkAWxwYWyMHMmAAGjgAIkN7E2KnKgNcky0wiKiY2rcPFSg4FFYGyO5m8rgAXmq6OnEmFih2AHIACxRuCHTpguFlVQ12NWTgQ0iktyA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the question mark for in a Typescript parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name) 
@mcoolive commented an answer to add information for the meaning of ?.

Comment: @97amarnathk same as the other commenter; I can't replicate your issue. When I put that into the playground, it infers `value` as `string | undefined` correctly. You may need to provide more information about your tsconfig.

Comment: @BenWainwright yes. 
I checked the tsconfig further and found that it was configured to not do strict checking for null and undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the same type inference was not reproducible on typescript playground, I checked the `tsconfig`, and found the following config

```json
{
  ...
  "strictNullChecks": false
}
```

On setting the above to `true`, it is working as expected now.