# How can I display the fetched data in my template?

Tags: angular

I created a file with the name of `product.ts` and then I added these codes to it:

```
export interface Product
{
    id:number;

}
```

component:

```
export class AppComponent {
   
  title = 'angpr';

  todo:Product;  

  constructor(public api: ApiService) {

  

  }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getApi()
  .subscribe(    
    data => this.todo=data
  );}


}
```

after importing the interface and using  `todo:Product;`  in the above code, I got this error:  `Property 'todo' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

The goal of using interface is displaying the fetched data in my template with using `{{todo.id}}`.

How can I display the fetched data in my template?

How can I solve this error: `Property 'todo' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`?

Comment: Can you write the full code for that component including your import and services in your question? Let me try your error.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as optional, as it can be optional.

```js
todo?:Product;
```

Comment: That's wrong. OP should declare it with the `!` since the value is getting assigned later.

Comment: I declared it with `!` and I got this error: 

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi that's you who are wrong. If the value is assigned LATER, it means until LATER, the value is undefined.

Comment: The error @dfs is writing is the exact reason why it's `?` and not `!`.

Comment: That's right, undefined. Not optional. more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632760/what-is-the-question-mark-for-in-a-typescript-parameter-name). The reason you're getting the cannot read property of undefined is because you need to put an `?` in your html: `{{todo?.id}}`.

Comment: I used `?` and I got this error: `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

Then I used `{{todo?.id}}` in the template, and there is no error, but there is nothing to see as the `id` value.

Comment: @dfs then it's because either your view is not updated, or your HTTP return value is incorrect. Check both !